# Conditionally wrap HTML elements

Tags: list, jsf, seam

In my Seam application, I have a Seam component that returns a (`@Datamodel`) list of items I want to transform into a set of `<li>` HTML elements. I have this working without a problem.

But now, I want to split up the list according to an EL expression. So the EL expression determines if a new `<ul>` element should be started. I tried the following:

```
<s:fragment rendered="#{action.isNewList(index)}">
  <ul>
</s:fragment>
<!-- stuff that does the <li>'s goes here -->
<s:fragment rendered="#{action.isNewList(index)}">
  </ul>
</s:fragment>
```

But that's invalid, because the nesting for `<ul>` is wrong.

How should I do this?

Comment: We need to see how you are iterating. Please post more code.

Comment: As well as the output of said code so we can see what's invalid about the nesting.

Comment: there's no output, but it's clearly not well-formed xml, since the nesting goes <a><b></a></b>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the JSF `<f:verbatim>` tag, which isn't pretty but works:

```
<f:verbatim rendered="#{action.isNewList(index)}">
  &lt;ul&gt;
</f:verbatim>
<!-- stuff that does the <li>'s goes here -->
<f:verbatim rendered="#{action.isNewList(index)}">
  &lt;/ul&gt;
</f:verbatim>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Seam Framework, but if I understand the problem correctly something like this might work.

```
<!-- before your loop, open your first <ul> if the (@Datamodel) is not empty -->

<s:fragment rendered="#{action.isNewList(index)}">
  </ul>
  <ul>
</s:fragment>
<!-- stuff that does the <li>'s goes here -->

<!-- after your loop, close your last </ul> if the (@Datamodel) is not empty -->
```

Comment: No that doesn't work, because the nesting of the xml is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Seam specifically, but I've seen this same problem come up when working with XSLT and other XML-based frameworks.

There are generally two solutions:

1. Rethink your page and data architecture so that the entire list written depending on a single condition.  This may require a loop inside the s:fragment.
2. Wrap the offending non-valid fragment html in a <![CDATA[  ... ]]>

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this (i will use pseudo code):

```
<ul>
    <s:for items="itemList" ...>

      <s:fragment rendered="#{action.isNewList(index) && index > 0}">
        </ul>
        <ul>
      </s:fragment>
      <li>
        <!-- stuff that does the <li>'s goes here -->
      </li>

    </s:for>
</ul>
```